# Angular: ¿Cómo iterar sobre un arreglo?

Tags: javascript, array, angular, typescript, iteradores

Tengo una duda tal vez alguien me podría explicar:

Recibo el siguiente arreglo:

```
afiliado{
    "attentionSchedules": [
        {
            "room": "200",
            "floor": 2,
            "schedules": [
                {
                    "days": [
                        "MO",
                        "TU",
                        "FR",
                        "TH",
                        "WE"
                    ],
                    "_id": "x",
                    "initialTimeStr": "07:00 am",
                    "finalTimeStr": "04:00 pm",
                    "initialTime": "2020-11-12T13:00:00.000Z",
                    "finalTime": "2020-11-12T22:00:00.000Z"
                }
            ],
            "place": {
                "loc": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        -88.0351328,
                        15.4876832
                    ]
                },
                "_id": "x",
                "name": "x",
                "address": "x"
            }
        },
        {
            "room": "",
            "schedules": [
                {
                    "days": [
                        "MO",
                        "TH",
                        "FR",
                        "TU"
                    ],
                    "_id": "x",
                    "initialTimeStr": "01:00 pm",
                    "finalTimeStr": "11:00 pm",
                    "initialTime": "2020-10-15T19:00:00.000Z",
                    "finalTime": "2020-10-16T05:00:00.000Z"
                }
            ],
            "place": {
                "loc": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        -88.01386190000001,
                        15.5038827
                    ]
                },
                "_id": "x",
                "name": "x",
                "address": "x"
            }
        }
    ],
}
```

Yo quiero acceder a "days", pero quiero iterar sobre "x" cantidad de objetos que venga dentro del arreglo. Es decir, que si en el arreglo "attentionSchedules" viene hasta 5 objetos, yo deberia poder iterarlos y obtener days, ¿Cómo puede iterar sobre este tipo de arreglos?

Agradeceria mucho su ayuda, ya que estoy un poco confundida con el tema porfavor

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacer un arreglo de los afiliados e iterar de esta manera:

```js
let afiliados = [{
  "attentionSchedules": [{
      "room": "200",
      "floor": 2,
      "schedules": [{
        "days": [
          "MO",
          "TU",
          "FR",
          "TH",
          "WE"
        ],
        "_id": "x",
        "initialTimeStr": "07:00 am",
        "finalTimeStr": "04:00 pm",
        "initialTime": "2020-11-12T13:00:00.000Z",
        "finalTime": "2020-11-12T22:00:00.000Z"
      }],
      "place": {
        "loc": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [-88.0351328,
            15.4876832
          ]
        },
        "_id": "x",
        "name": "x",
        "address": "x"
      }
    },
    {
      "room": "",
      "schedules": [{
        "days": [
          "MO",
          "TH",
          "FR",
          "TU"
        ],
        "_id": "x",
        "initialTimeStr": "01:00 pm",
        "finalTimeStr": "11:00 pm",
        "initialTime": "2020-10-15T19:00:00.000Z",
        "finalTime": "2020-10-16T05:00:00.000Z"
      }],
      "place": {
        "loc": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [-88.01386190000001,
            15.5038827
          ]
        },
        "_id": "x",
        "name": "x",
        "address": "x"
      }
    }
  ],
}]


afiliados.forEach(afiliado => {
  afiliado.attentionSchedules.forEach(attentionSchedule => {
    attentionSchedule.schedules.forEach(schedules => {
      console.log(schedules.days)
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Primero: debemos analizar la estructura del objeto afiliado para entender qué funciones podríamos ir usando para sacar los items que necesitemos.

Segundo: al entender la estructura vemos que tenemos dos niveles a trabajar: schedules y finalmente days.

Tercero: accedemos al primer elemento que necesitamos extraer (schedules)

Cuarto: Al tener schedules definido, podemos hacer otro bucle (en este caso sobre schedules) y extraer days. Con ello, ya tenemos resuelto el problema.

```js
const afiliado = {
    "attentionSchedules": [
        {
            "room": "200",
            "floor": 2,
            "schedules": [
                {
                    "days": [
                        "MO",
                        "TU",
                        "FR",
                        "TH",
                        "WE"
                    ],
                    "_id": "x",
                    "initialTimeStr": "07:00 am",
                    "finalTimeStr": "04:00 pm",
                    "initialTime": "2020-11-12T13:00:00.000Z",
                    "finalTime": "2020-11-12T22:00:00.000Z"
                }
            ],
            "place": {
                "loc": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        -88.0351328,
                        15.4876832
                    ]
                },
                "_id": "x",
                "name": "x",
                "address": "x"
            }
        },
        {
            "room": "",
            "schedules": [
                {
                    "days": [
                        "MO",
                        "TH",
                        "FR",
                        "TU"
                    ],
                    "_id": "x",
                    "initialTimeStr": "01:00 pm",
                    "finalTimeStr": "11:00 pm",
                    "initialTime": "2020-10-15T19:00:00.000Z",
                    "finalTime": "2020-10-16T05:00:00.000Z"
                }
            ],
            "place": {
                "loc": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        -88.01386190000001,
                        15.5038827
                    ]
                },
                "_id": "x",
                "name": "x",
                "address": "x"
            }
        }
    ],
}

let schedules = []
let days = []

afiliado.attentionSchedules.forEach(element => {
    schedules.push({
        days: element.schedules[0].days
    })
});

schedules.forEach(element => {
    days.push(element.days)
});

console.log(days)
```

Comment: yo creo que quiza se refiera tambien a que puden haber varios schedules en este ejemplo pone uno solo pero x ejemplo el lunes y martes es de 1pm a 3pm y de miercoles a viernes de 8am a 10am. En este caso tu respuesta no retorna todos los dias de atencion. @Izlia confirma...

Comment: En ese caso el arreglo es distinto y se opera de forma distinta. Pero, para el ejemplo que @sgClaudia98 dió puede servir lo que he enviado. Saludos.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).